Azure B2C Custom Policy split Email verification and Email change page
I have forgot password flow in my custom policies
I have next flow

Verify current email using OTP
2

On the same popup(page) button for change email

If change email than enter a new one + email verification

Password change


Are there ways to split this functionality into two separate technical profiles?

Email verification page + css to hide changeEmail button

Email change page(there a problem)

Password Change



`    <UserJourney Id="PasswordReset">
      <OrchestrationSteps>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="PasswordResetUsingEmailAddressExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountDiscoveryUsingEmailAddress" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="NewCredentials" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountWritePasswordUsingObjectId" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="SendClaims" CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="JwtIssuer" />
      </OrchestrationSteps>
      <ClientDefinition ReferenceId="DefaultWeb" />
    </UserJourney>`

        <TechnicalProfile Id="LocalAccountDiscoveryUsingEmailAddress">
          <DisplayName>Reset password using email address</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="IpAddressClaimReferenceId">IpAddress</Item>
            <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.localaccountpasswordreset</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <CryptographicKeys>
            <Key Id="issuer_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_TokenSigningKeyContainer" />
          </CryptographicKeys>
          <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="Verified.Email" Required="true" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userPrincipalName" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" />
          </OutputClaims>
          <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
            <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingEmailAddress" />
          </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
        </TechnicalProfile>


Check if this helps https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/split-email-verification-and-signup
